# Failed to compile htmlparser2 reactjs

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

Failed to compile on npm start, Reactjs

/node_modules/htmlparser2/lib/esm/index.js 62:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (62:9)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |   return getFeed(parseDOM(feed, options));
  | }

> export * as DomUtils from "domutils";
> | // Old name for DomHandler
> | export { DomHandler as DefaultHandler };